# Calling functions implicitly from derived classes

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, software-design

In my main.cpp I have something similar to the following:

```
void OnEventStart(int id)
{
    // Do some stuff
}
```

This function is a callback, it is only triggered (by the main sdk that this is from) when an event has occured.

I now have this class:

```
class SomeClass {
public:
    void OnEventStart(int id);
};

void SomeClass::OnEventStart(int id)
{
    // Do some other stuff
}
```

Now I want to trigger `void SomeClass::OnEventStart(int id)` without doing something like this:

```
SomeClass class;
void OnEventStart(int id)
{
     // Do some stuff

     class.OnEventStart(id);

     // AnotherClass.OnEventStart(id);
     // Another.OnEventStart(id);
}
```

As you can imagine, using a method like this can easily clutter up the inital function/callback.

Comment: I assume you want the framework/SDK that you are using to call your member function directly? Then it depends *a lot* on the actual framework/SDK you are using. It might not even be possible. But we can't tell you unless you tell us the framework/SDK and how you use it (with a a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)). Also please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: imho it would help to understand the question if you tell us how you would like to do it, not only how you dont want to do it

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear, but I'll assume the following:

- You have some sort of callback handler that takes a `void(*)(int)`.

In that case, if `SomeClass` is stateless, you can simply use a lambda wrapper:

```
my_framework_callback([]{ SomeClass{}.OnEventStart(id); });
```

---

If I misunderstood what you were asking, here's a different assumption:

- `SomeClass` and similar types are **stateless**.
- You're annoyed by having to instantiate `SomeClass` just to call one of its methods.

If that's the case, you can create a *temporary instance* of `SomeClass` on the spot:

```
void OnEventStart(int id)
{
     SomeClass{}.OnEventStart(id);
     AnotherClass{}.OnEventStart(id);
     Another{}.OnEventStart(id);
}
```

---

If your question is instead...

> *"I have various classes with the same interface, and I want to call a function on all of them."*

...then one possible solution would be using an *abstract base class* that provides `.OnEventStart() = 0` and store an `std::vector` of pointers to that base class.

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<MyAbstractClass>> handlers;
void OnEventStart(int id)
{
    for(auto& h : handlers)
        h->OnEventStart(id);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sorry for the question being unclear, the problem I'm having you addressed in the second part of your post. Wouldn't this method require me to instantiate each class (which there will be many) and then proceed to `handlers.push_back(class)` for every single class?

Comment: @thefatshizms: you can do this in a lot of different ways. If you know all the types at compile-time, you could use a metaprogramming library and a compile-time list. If you're allowing users of your code to add more types that satisfy the interface, you need to do what you mentioned, maybe providing some sort of `register<T>()` function.